# Convert timestamp string to DateTime object in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-phone-8

I have timestamp strings in the following format `5/1/2012 3:38:27 PM`. How do I convert it to a DateTime object in c#

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted what you have tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You input string looks like in `en-us` format, which is `M/d/yyyy h/mm/ss tt`. You have to use proper `CultureInfo` instance while parsing:

```
var ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us");

var value = DateTime.Parse("5/1/2012 3:38:27 PM", ci);
```

or

```
var ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us");
```

Comment: Thanks, this should work but I am developing on Windows Phone. GetCultureInfo does not contain in `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`?

Comment: `DateTime.Parse` seems to expect a `System.IFormatProvider` so `ci` is marked as invalid argument

Comment: Ah sorry my mistake, you are correct. I was using a date variable which wasn't a string object.

Comment: @PutraKg `CultureInfo` implements `IFormatPrivider` ;)

Answer (score 8):

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("5/1/2012 3:38:27 PM", 
    "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try to use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method like;

```
string s = "5/1/2012 3:38:27 PM";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. **The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.**

Output will be;

```
01.05.2012 15:38:27
```

***Be aware***, this output can change based which Culture you used. Since my `Culture` is `tr-TR`, the date operator is `.` our culture.

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/Jixshl).

Answer (score 1):

Try the [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14743/Easy-String-to-DateTime-DateTime-to-String-and-For
this maybe helps you. There you can find a detailled explanation of the ParseExact parameters.