# Convert a sql string output to timestamp with C#

Tags: c#, sql, json, timestamp

I have a SQL output that comes with different fields. A couple of those fields are dates and I want to convert them to timestamp. Here is how the output of the dates look as it comes from the database:

```
4/6/2016 9:00:00 PM
```

And when converted to JSON it looks like this:

```
opening_date":"4/6/2016 9:00:00 PM"
```

I tried the following to convert the SQL request output

```
meeting_start_date = DateTime.ParseExact((string)((object[])((ArrayList)results)[i])[3].ToString(), "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

as per what I found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103186/convert-timestamp-string-to-datetime-object-in-c-sharp), but I get the following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

is there something wrong with how I am using the function, or is there a better way to make the conversion from the SQL output to timestamp so it can be added to the json output.

Comment: Is `meeting_start_date` a string? Otherwise, what exactly is the type of `results`?

Comment: @Wimmel the `meeting_start_date` should be a string but it is originally a `datetime` in sql

Comment: If you need a string, why do you convert it into a DateTime first? The output from the database looks identical to the format you need in the json.

Comment: Why should it be a string?  If it's a datetime, keep it as a datetime object

Comment: If you model holds DateTime property, it'll be serialized just fine using e.g. JSON.NET

Comment: I need it as a string but I want it to convert it to epoch i.e. `4/6/2016 9:00:00 PM` to `1459947600000`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453101/how-do-i-get-epoch-time-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do to fix this error is after parsing your DateTime, end it with a `ToString()`. This will allow you to assign the value to a string variable like so

```
meeting_start_date = DateTime.ParseExact((string)((object[])((ArrayList)results)[i])[3].ToString(), "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();
```

As a side note, in this part `(string)((object[])((ArrayList)results)[i])[3].ToString()` you are casting the value as a string even though you used `ToString()` on it already